# How to include months in a daily plot of time series data in R

Tags: r, date, plot, time-series

I have a plot of daily volatility in R

[image]

The dates range from "2009-04-01" to "2010-07-01", and it is kept in that format in R. 
When I plot it,

> plot(d, vol1, type="l")

I only get the year 'labels' on the x axis. However, it would be helpful to have the month 'labels' as well. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You can create a manual x axis: `plot (d, type="l", axes=FALSE) axis(1,1:12,c("JAN","FEB","MAR",'APR',"MAY", "JUN", "JUL","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC"))` modify as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `axis` command to draw it manually.

### Example 1

```
# test data
d <- seq(as.Date("2009-04-01"), as.Date("2010-07-01"), "day")
v <- seq_along(d)

plot(v ~ d, xaxt = "n")

# draw X axis
months <- seq(min(d), max(d), "month")
axis(1, months, format(months, "%Y\n%b"))
```

giving:

[image: screenshot]

### Example 2

```
# test data
d <- seq(as.Date("2009-04-01"), as.Date("2010-07-01"), "day")
v <- seq_along(d)

plot(v ~ d, xaxt = "n")

# draw X axis
months <- seq(min(d), max(d), "month")
lab <- format(months, "%b")
lab[lab == "Jan"] <- format(months, "%Y")[lab == "Jan"]
axis(1, months, lab)
```

giving:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tidyverse` tools to do this pretty simply, particularly `scale_x_date` option `date_breaks`. You can also look at other answers on here or web resources if you want to do additional customisation.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df = tibble(
  days = seq.Date(from = ymd("2009-04-01"), to = ymd("2010-07-01"), by = "day"),
  value = rnorm(457)
  )

ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_line(aes(x = days, y = value)) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%m-%y")
```

[image]